# Adjusting tab width in C++

Tags: c++

Is there any way to adjust tab width in the console?

Comment: Why do you need that? You should allow user to use his favorite tab size and your program should work correctly in any user environment.

Comment: Is that on Windows, some flavor of Unix, OS X, or the debugging console for the chip that runs my dishwasher? There's certainly no way to do that in standard C++. There _might_ be an OS-specific way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know until you elaborate more in your question but there's the possibility you just want to write some justified text out to the console, if this is the case you could:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

and use:

```
std::setw
```

or possibly

```
std::ios
std::setiosflags
std::resetiosflags
```

Difficult to know unless you give us more detail in your question...

Answer (score 2):

That's not really a C++ question since the console depends entirely on the underlying environment. For example, I know of no way to do this with the `cmd.exe` window under Windows.

I thought there *may* be a way to do this with `stty` under UNIX-like operating systems but I can't find it after a cursory search.

One possibility is to pass the output through a separate filter program like:

```
yourprogram | expand --tabs=4
```

but this is outside the scope of your C++ application.

If you want to be able to do this in C++ portably, you'll probably have to subclass one of the output streams so that you can keep a record of your current column number and translate tab characters into the correct number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find GetConsoleWindow() from msdn.
And you may refer to http://www.adrianxw.dk/SoftwareSite/Consoles/Consoles6.html